# Change hamburger icon color in Vue Bootstrap

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu, bootstrap-vue

I want to change the Vue Bootstrap Hamburger navbar-toggler-icon to a color of white.

I tried every combination of code I can think of without luck. When I load the app the CSS reverts back to the original bootstrap url. Any ideas?

This is what I am trying in the style section:

```
 .navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)") !important;
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: What is the CSS you tried?

Comment: I might be getting my terminology wrong but I used the code above in the <style> portion of the vue app to target the navbar toggler icon without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS to change the color of the toggler.
You can change the `stroke` on the `<path>` to the colour you want.

If you are using a scoped style tag in your vue component (`<style scoped>`), then you might need to use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) to properly target the toggle icon.

```css
.navbar-toggler-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'><path stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/></svg>") !important;
}
```

I found this specific CSS on the Bootstrap github [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/dca1ab7d877bc4b664b43604657a2b5fbe2b4ecb/scss/_variables.scss#L749)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        // A column that needs custom formatting
        { key: 'name', label: 'Full Name' },
        { key: 'age', label: 'Age' },
        { key: 'sex', label: 'Sex' }
      ],
      items: [
        { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Male', age: 42 },
        { name: { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Female', age: 36 },
        { name: { first: 'Rubin', last: 'Kincade' }, sex: 'Male', age: 73 },
        { name: { first: 'Shirley', last: 'Partridge' }, sex: 'Female', age: 62 }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.navbar-toggler-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'><path stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/></svg>") !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-navbar toggleable="xl" type="dark" variant="info">
    <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>

    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item href="#">Link</b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</div>
```

Comment: You were right. I had to use the deep selector to properly target the icon! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the default color options from the documentation.
When you set the `type` to `dark` or `light` it will display a white or black icon.

Reference: Vue-Bootstrap Navbar: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/navbar